# Check if values from the list exist in another list without additional characters

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists:

```
a = ["ad", "news", "something else", "another something"]
c = ["coupon", "ad"]
```

List **a** (and **c** ) must contain only characters from list **b**. Also in the list **a**(and **c** ) can be missed characters from list **b** but the characters from the list be must appear or partially :

```
b = ["coupon", "ad", "news"]
```

As a result, list **a** (because it contains additional characters) is wrong and list **c** is OK (although- it doesn't have "news").

I started writing nested if and I am stuck

```
for x in ["coupon", "ad", "news"]:
    for z in ["ad", "news", "something else", "another something"]:
        print(x,z)
```

Comment: would `c` be OK if it were `c = ["coup", "ad"]`?

Comment: @enke - No, it will not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have defined 2 functions.

The first one will take in 2 lists of strings, and return if any of the strings in the first list exists in the second list:

```
def validate(lst1, lst2):
    return all(i in lst2 for i in lst1)

a = ["ad", "news", "something else", "another something"]
c = ["coupon", "ad"]

b = ["coupon", "ad", "news"]

print(validate(a, b))
print(validate(c, b))
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

The second one checks if all the characters used the each string in the first list exists in any of the strings in the second list:

```
def validate(lst1, lst2):
    characters = ''.join(lst2)
    return all(j in characters for i in lst1 for j in i)

a = ["ad", "news", "something else", "another something"]
c = ["coupon", "ad"]

b = ["coupon", "ad", "news"]

print(validate(a, b))
print(validate(c, b))
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for `set.issubset`:

```
for k, lst in {'a': a, 'c': c}.items():
    if set(lst).issubset(b):
        print(f'{k} is OK')
    else:
        print(f'{k} is not OK')
```

Output:

```
a is not OK
c is OK
```

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary I thought *characters* meant strings, so that if `c = ["coup", "ad"]`, it would not be OK

Answer (score 0):

Check if in list 'a' there is an element not present in 'b'

```
for x in a:
    if x not in b:
        print("Not correct")
```